# Textarea with validation on Angularjs wont Work in internet Explorer 11 AngularJS

Tags: css, angularjs, html, internet-explorer-11

My code in angularjs, where i have a textarea with required atribute is allways dirty no matter what i input. Its important to remark that this works for every other browser beside this dude.

Here is the code and an image.

```
      <div ng-class="{'pmo-error': showError('resumeACSO')}">
      <textarea ng-model="currentModel().ResumeACSO" ng-required="true" name="resumeACSO" class="form-control textarea" ng-attr-placeholder="{{'PMO_RESUMEACSO_PLACEHOLDER' | translate}}">{{currentModel().ResumeACSO}}</textarea>           
       <span ng-show="showError('resumeACSO')">
            {{'ERROR_MSG_REQUIRED' | translate}}
        </span>
    </div>
    </br>
    <p>{{'PMO_RESUMEACSO_FOOTER' | translate}}</p>
```

UPDATE: The problem looks to be that the binding is not working in internet explorer.

Comment: Why are you binding `ngModel` using a function? I don't recall seeing a lot of this practice, and I think for a good reason

Comment: And BTW, [check this](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie) (Section 4): _For the placeholder attribute of textarea, use `ng-attr-placeholder` tags instead of `placeholder="{{ someExpression }}"`. If using the latter, **Internet Explorer will error** on accessing the `nodeValue` on a parentless `TextNode` in Internet Explorer 10 & 11..._ - Perhaps it's related to your issue

Comment: i will lookup to that, but i ask because im searching for some solution , the ng-attr-placeholder is already in the code

Comment: i update the code

Comment: OK, so first I would recommend 2 things: **1.** DON'T bind `ngModel` using a function. In your controller you can create an object, for example `$scope.params = { ResumeACSO: null }` and then bind it like this: `ng-model="params.ResumeACSO"`. **2.** Check [this link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMessages/directive/ngMessages) with information about displaying validation messages using the `ngMessage` module

Comment: More examples about `ngMessage` can be found [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMessages) and [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/easy-form-validation-angularjs-ngmessages/) (Extra example of showing the error if the field is dirty

Comment: the ng-model with a function is a business i cant break

Comment: Can you create a working example of this bug so I can test it locally?

Comment: im trying to do that, it may take a few hours